# If Else Conditional statement in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, sh

**Value of a Variable in Shell Script based on the condition mentioned in the IF statement.**

I have a shell script, I want to assign a variable based on the condition in `if` statement.

For Eg:

```
    build(){
    
     SRC_TBL=$1

     filename=`echo $SRC_TBL | sed 's/_//g'`

     target_tbl=`echo $SRC_TBL | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`

     if [["${target_tbl}" == "DEMO" ]];then
        target_tbl= "TEST"
     fi
    
    }

build "DEMO"
```

I am running the above function, so according to the logic the value of the variable target_tbl should be TEST, but it is still DEMO.

Help me where am I going wrong

Comment: check your script with shellcheck

Comment: Can you put the exact script you are using? This one does not work, and your issue probably is in one of those details you didn't care here.

Comment: "Does not work" in the sense that it tries to execute `[[DEMO` as a command.  And if that were fixed then there is at least one other error that would interfere with the result you seem to expect.  You should be getting some kind of diagnostic indicating the nature of the issue, unless you are suppressing it.  This sort of thing is among the reasons that we request that people posing debugging questions provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.  Not only does that help us help you, but often it even helps you to help yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your script.

1. assignment must NOT have spaces around `=`
2. there MUST be a space after `[[`

Here's the script fixed and working fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


build() {

  SRC_TBL=$1

  filename=$(echo "$SRC_TBL" | sed 's/_//g')

  target_tbl=$(echo "$SRC_TBL" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')

  if [[ "$target_tbl" == "DEMO" ]]; then
    target_tbl="TEST"
  fi
  printf "%s" "$target_tbl"
}

build "DEMO"
```

[image]

some resources for the future:

https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-bash-bible

https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: There's further room for optimization. `filename=${SRC_TBL//_/}` for example is a lot faster than using `sed` (and certainly gets you closer to writing "pure bash")

Comment: And `target_tbl=${SRC_TBL^^}` is a lot faster than using `tr`.